# Updating child array in reducer using React Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reducers

I am doing some filtering using React Context and I am having some difficulty in updating a child's array value when a filter is selected.

I want to be able to filter by a minimum price, which is selected in a dropdown by the user, I then dispatch an action to store that in the reducers state, however, when I try and update an inner array (homes: []) that lives inside the developments array (which is populated with data on load), I seem to wipe out the existing data which was outside the inner array?

In a nutshell, I need to be able to maintain the existing developments array, and filter out by price within the homes array, I have provided a copy of my example code before, please let me know if I have explained this well enough!

```js
export const initialState = {
  priceRange: {
    min: null
  },
  developments: []
};


// Once populated on load, the developments array (in the initialState object) 
// will have a structure like this, 
// I want to be able to filter the developments by price which is found below

developments: [
  name: 'Foo',
  location: 'Bar',
  distance: 'xxx miles',
  homes: [
    {
      name: 'Foo',
      price: 100000
    },
    {
      name: 'Bar',
      price: 200000
    }
  ]
]

case 'MIN_PRICE':
  return {
    ...state,
    priceRange: {
      ...state.priceRange,
      min: action.payload
    },
    developments: [
      ...state.developments.map(development => {
      // Something here is causing it to break I believe?
        development.homes.filter(house => house.price < action.payload);
      })
    ]
  };
```

```html
<Select onChange={event=>
  dropdownContext.dispatch({ type: 'MIN_PRICE' payload: event.value }) } />
```

Comment: Once I have fetched the data from the API, it returns an array of objects, that's why I left it as an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to separate homes from the other properties, then you can apply the filter and rebuild a development object:

```
return = {
    ...state,
    priceRange: {
        ...state.priceRange,
        min: action.payload
    },
    developments: state.developments.map(({homes, ...other}) => {
        return {
            ...other, 
            homes: homes.filter(house => house.price < action.payload)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your above answer @HermitCrab, If I was to add a maxPrice range, and copy your answer above but change the `house.price > action.payload`...

Would filter be the best approach here? As if the result is 0, i believe it won't show anything again as it's been filtered?

Comment: If no house matches your filter, then homes will be an empty array [ ]

Comment: Is it possible to reset the value back to the initial state? If it would match the filter after it is 0? Sorry I am new to this and really appreciate your help!

Comment: It must be possible but it won't be easy and the resulting code might be ugly and very hard to debug. Question: why do you need to mutate this complex object? Couldn't you just filter it when you render it

Comment: Is there an easier approach to this then? I am new to using Context/Reducers, is this approach more complex than it needs to be? If so, please can you explain why and how you'd approach it instead?

Comment: I would keep developments and filter (priceRange) in 2 different objects, I would then just update the filter object and pass both to the component in charge of rendering the results of your search. In this component, I would map developments and then map homes and render only the homes matching the filter criteria. This way you always have all the houses in your developments array and you don't need to fetch them again when the user changes his price range

Comment: Ahhh I think I understand what you mean, currently, though, the development array is separate from the priceRange? So do you advise to keep the same setup as we have here? Just render the homes depending on the filter - if that makes sense?

Comment: Yes, this is how I would do it

Comment: I will look to implement that as it makes more sense, I am going to restructure my data to something like 

filters: {
   priceRange: { .... }
},
developments: []

Is that how you'd expect it to work?